# Colab finishes with a ^C

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm running a laplacian pyramid program on Colab that is not vectorized so it takes it's time and when it gets to `def vizpyramid()` it just exits per below:

```
100% 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 23.74it/s]
def computestack
len grayimgs 2
gray_imgs[0] shape (500, 333)
len lapylpyrcolor 3, len lapylpyrcolor[0] 5
len lapylpyrcolor 3, len lapylpyrcolor[0] 5
fusedgray shape (500, 333)
def vizpyramid
^C
```

Most of those are from `print` statements except the `100%...` and `^C`.  I did not push control-C so what is happening?  I have checked the function and it works fine on my local machine.

Edit:  I tried switching to a `None` no-GPU runtime and now it won't even run with a `!python main.py` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"^C" appears for multiple types of interrupt in Colab I noticed. Even if you just press on the stop button (to interrupt execution of a cell) it shows "^C". 
I can't think of any other reasons why it would show a "^C"

Comment: I did not push it unless Colab queues previous multiple clicks on the stop button and uses those somehow on the next run and next run and next run, etc.  I'll try to reproduce it and write steps here.

Comment: Here is probably what happened.  I had the cell highlighted or clicked on, moved my cursor away to a tab in Chrome, etc and unknowingly pushed a key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 12):

I met the same problem when I ran python in  colab. I found that because the list I generated was too large, it should have occupied all the memory.

Comment: this should be the correct answer