# Issues in Tensorflow model training

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to run a pretrained tensorflow object detection model with my own datasets in google collab.
But getting this unknown errors while running the training. I tried changing the batch size=2, and steps=20000, but still the same errors. The error is:

```
2024-03-01 11:15:07.851290: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-03-01 11:15:14.012057: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:268] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
I0301 11:15:14.048205 139949003751424 mirrored_strategy.py:419] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 20000
I0301 11:15:14.210126 139949003751424 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 20000
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0301 11:15:14.210465 139949003751424 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0301 11:15:14.290481 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
I0301 11:15:14.314484 139949003751424 dataset_builder.py:162] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
I0301 11:15:14.314929 139949003751424 dataset_builder.py:79] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/train.tfrecord']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0301 11:15:14.315054 139949003751424 dataset_builder.py:80] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0301 11:15:14.315170 139949003751424 dataset_builder.py:86] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
W0301 11:15:14.353366 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0301 11:15:14.419352 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /content/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0301 11:15:24.248110 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0301 11:15:28.897560 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0301 11:15:32.042234 139949003751424 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2024-03-01 11:15:35.407217: W tensorflow/core/framework/dataset.cc:956] Input of GeneratorDatasetOp::Dataset will not be optimized because the dataset does not implement the AsGraphDefInternal() method needed to apply optimizations.
^C
```

I noticed that my system ram has gone almost at its peak just before stopping the training.Is it something due to this?
[system ram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRDL3.png)

Comment: There are no errors in the provided output, only warnings. Is something missing?

Comment: Its just stopping the training with ^C. I noticed my system memory went its peak just before stopping. is it something due to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305202/7750891

Comment: Can you kindly add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From merely the logs its difficult to make out what could have went wrong.

Comment: Well, the size of my input images was the problem. They were too large and due to that reason the system memory was going at it's peak and stopping.